# On three.js / editor

Tags: three.js

I am trying to make a Newton's Cradle on three.js. I am wondering how would I make it so that the balls are able to be pulled and let go so that then they can hit the others and click back and forth?

Answer (score 3):

that is a pretty huge undertaking and not something someone will give you detailed instructions for on this site :) This is probably the reason why your question is downvoted. It's not meant to demotivate you but simply that your question is way too broad. Here are some hints, and definitely come back with more detailed questions once you are on your way:

- you need a physics-engine. Have a look at [Physijs](https://chandlerprall.github.io/Physijs/) or [cannon.js](http://schteppe.github.io/cannon.js/) which 
  both work well with three.js.
- you need some interactions in order to drag one of the balls. For this you will need to understand [this demo](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_interactive_draggablecubes.html)

but that should be it. You'll need to learn how the physics-engine works, but it will handle all the complicated stuff for you :)